# I've got problems with textarea, button and its layout

Tags: html, css, button, textarea, placeholder

I do the task for FCC to make a Survey Form. At the end of the page  tag doesn't expand along with the whole page, when it's less 680px; also  goes to the right when applies the same @media.

I've tried changing "display" option to "block" to make button start from the new line, but it doesn't work

```
  border-radius: 5px;
  resize: both;
  border-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 40px;
  width: 96px;
  border: 0px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Here's the link to full code in case you need some more info:

https://codepen.io/vadimketov1/pen/BXZXxb

I expect textarea to expand properly vertically with the whole page and button to be on the middle so it doesn't go right

Comment: on smaller screen remove the unset the float property for the .right class. That should bring the submit button down.

Answer (score 1):

In the media query add class with `width: 100%;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .textarea{
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

and in you html add the class here

```
<div class="right textarea">
    <textarea name="comment" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your comment here">           
    </textarea>
</div>
```